# Download Files in Atom Plugin

Tags: atom-editor

I'm building an Atom plugin and I need to download executable files according to the OS I'm running on. Is there a good practice of where to store such files?

Comment: What executable files?

Comment: I'm developing Arduino plugin so it's the Arduino tools such as avr

Comment: Honestly, I don't that's a good idea. It is common to install extra dependencies manually (see most build or linter providers – likely *all* that don't depend on a Node package) and there's probably good reason for it. Not to mention that you might need administrative rights to install binaries globally. Other than that, of course you can [download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/download) files in Node.

Comment: If you want to make setup easy, e.g. for employees at your company, I'd consider using a setup routine that installs your Atom package and all dependencies.

Comment: Yeah that was why I was asking 'what executables'. Non-apm dependencies should not be bundled with apm packages.

Comment: Of course I'll not bundle it with the package as its about 160mb per platform. As far as I know it doesn't require admin so doing a separate install seem bad experience to me. I'll look at exist plugins. Thank you.